# What is the proper screen reader accessible markup for a <button> that pauses the looping of a autoplayed presentation-only/eye-candy <video>?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

We have a looping video on our homepage that simply looks awesome and contains no information. Because the video is decorative and has no benefit for screen reader visitors, we've added `aria-hidden="true"` to the `<video>` element.

In order to meet accessibility requirements we also added a keyboard focusable pause button for this video on our homepage. Just a semantic `<button>` element with some javascript code hooked up to it to pause the video when pressed. So now keyboard users with motion sensitivities can easily stop the video from looping.

According ARIA, `aria-hidden="true"` should never be used on a focusable element. Nor can element container have `aria-hidden="true"` on it and have focusable elements nested within it. We can't just add `aria-hidden="true"` to the `<button>` element and that appears to be the only ARIA acceptable way to hide something from screen readers. We also don't want to remove the ability for voice control assistive tools to use the button.

**How do we properly markup this `<button>` element for screen reader only users so that it is hidden or not confusing?** Considering that the button is controlling the `<video>` that is hidden with `aria-hidden="true"`.

Below is the current markup we use:

```html
<video aria-hidden="true" id="looping-video" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<button id="looping-video-pause-button">Pause Video</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where the rules do not apply.

Remember that they are guidelines, **real world usability is far more important than the guidelines.**

Wrap the button in a `div` and use `aria-hidden` on the `div` (as sometimes `aria-hidden` directly on an element gets ignored / causes strange behaviour).

Alternatively it is perfectly acceptable to tell screen reader users that there is a video element used for decoration and a basic overview of the video content (remember that the aim of accessibility is to provide as close to the same experience as possible for all users.).

If this is the case then the button will make sense and no need to hide it.

I think in your use case the former option (hide the button from the accessibility tree) is actually desirable as you said the video contains nothing more than decorative material.

### w3 guidance

Taken from https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden and https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden

> Authors MAY, with caution, use aria-hidden to hide visibly rendered content from assistive technologies only if the act of hiding this content is intended to improve the experience for users of assistive technologies by removing redundant or extraneous content.

p.s. bonus points for actually remembering people with movement / anxiety disorders :-)